# android API 8 not recognize value

Tags: android, xml, dimensions

I developed android app can support multiscreen size and for all versions from 2.2 to 4.2 
and i handling the dimensions on values directory like this:

value, value-sw320dp, value-sw360dp, value-sw480dp, value-sw600dp, value-sw800dp

On android 4.0.4 to 4.2.2 it's work fine.
But on android 2.2 to 3.2 take the value from default directory.

how i can make android 2.2 to 3.2 to determination the best value like android 4.0.4 to 4.2 ??

Comment: This [blog entry from Android Developer](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) is a good starting point. Basically, the `value-swXXXdp` is not supported before Android 3.2, so you have to use `value-large`, etc.